# Слайд-шоу на JQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста! Почему нельзя присвоить абсолютное позиционирование для слайда? Почему то при абсолютном позиционирование становятся видны по мимо первой картинки и остальные картинки. Как это можно исправить?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Слайд</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<Link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slide.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    start(0,0); }

var slide = 5;
var now_slide = 1;
var speed = 3000;
var width = 500;
function slider(ml)
{
    $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:ml+"px"},{queue: false},500);
}
function start(px,step)
{
    if(step == 0)
    {
        slider(px);
        px = px - width;
        now_slide++;
        if(now_slide == slide)setTimeout("start("+px+",1);",speed);
        else setTimeout("start("+px+",0);",speed);
    }

    if(step == 1)
    {
        slider(px);
        px = px + width;
        now_slide--;
        if(now_slide == 1)setTimeout("start("+px+",0);",speed); 
        else setTimeout("start("+px+",1);",speed);
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div style="height:334px;width:500px;border:1px solid #000;overflow:hidden;">
<table id="slide" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0px">
    <tr>
        <td width="500px"><img src="img/ime.jpg" border="0px"></td>
        <td width="500px"><img src="img/imr.jpg" border="0px"></td>
        <td width="500px"><img src="img/ims.jpg" border="0px"></td>
        <td width="500px"><img src="img/imt.jpg" border="0px"></td>
        <td width="500px"><img src="img/imv.jpg" border="0px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Arty21, нужен jsfiddle.

Comment: @Arty21, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: как добавить ручное управление подскажите?

Comment: был подобный вопрос. Даже есть фиддл, посмотрите, может что-то возьмете для себя - http://jsfiddle.net/Barton89/sbbdF/2/

Comment: В выше обозначенном фиддле имеется глюк, если в ручном управление перелистываешь до конца, и при попытке выйти на новый круг слайд клинит и перестает показывать фото, пока не нажмешь f5. Не понятно почему?

Comment: это просто не последняя версия была, сорри. Вот сделал новый, где все норм. как в авто, так и в ручном - http://jsfiddle.net/Barton89/w8ean/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй для таблицы сделать `position:relative;`

Comment: Все ломалось из-за того что я выдергивал слайд из окошка, который скрывал все лишнее. Спасибо ты оказался почти прав. В css я поставил position: absolute для div style и все получилось а ведь до этого пытался position: absolute поставить для table.

Comment: Если можешь подскажи пожалуйста. Как мне можно в 
этом коде установить ручное управления слайдом? Если можешь помоги!

Comment: проще всего по id делаешь id вида slide + i
    onclick ="$('#slide tr td').next('td').показ слайда"
что то на подобие этого, зачем делать слайдер есть куча готовых решений?
 и ещё советую убрать тебе таблицу сделать всё на дивах, проще будет и удобнее